# How to fix python returning multiple lines in a .csv document instead of one?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook, urllib

I am trying to scrape data form a public forum for a school project, but every-time I run the code, the resulting .csv file shows multiple rows for the text variable instead of just one.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

my_url = 'https://www.emimino.cz/diskuse/1ivf-repromeda-56566/'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_soup = soup(uClient.read(),"html.parser")
uClient.close()

containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"discussion_post"})


out_filename = "Repromeda.csv"
headers = "text,user_name,date \n"

f = open(out_filename, "w")
f.write(headers)

for container in containers:
    text1 = container.div.p
    text = text1.text

    user_container = container.findAll("span",{"class":"user_category"})
    user_id = user_container[0].text

    date_container = container.findAll("span",{"class":"date"})
    date = date_container[1].text

    print("text: " + text + "\n" )
    print("user_id: " + user_id + "\n")
    print("date: " + date + "\n")
    # writes the dataset to file
    f.write(text.replace(",", "|") + ", " + user_id + ", " + date + "\n")

f.close()
```

Ideally I am trying to create a row for each data entry (ie. text, user_id, date in one row), but instead I get multiple rows for one text entry and only one row for user_id and date entry.

[this is the actual output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eddg6.png)

[this is the expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciuVx.png)

Comment: can you post the actual output & expected?

Comment: @Sureshmani Yes, done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the new line with blank string.

```
for container in containers:
   text1 = container.div.p
   text = text1.text.replace('\n', ' ')
```